# Spotify always starts and I’d like it not to on my Mac

Tags: macos, user-account, applications, spotify

My computer just ran out of batteries, so I plugged it in and started it up. Spotify began to open, but I did not want it to be open so I used right click-force quit. The application stayed open, but did not open any windows and said it was Not Responding.

I attempted to force quit it again multiple ways, and to uninstall the application but nothing has worked.

Where is a Spotify uninstall document or tool so I can remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried disabling it from the startup login? If not try this.

- Click on the Apple menu > System Preferences > System > Uses & Groups.
  Click on Login Items.
- The list of apps which are automatically launched when you login, will be displayed in this section.
- Uncheck the items you don't really need.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I was looking for. I was wondering less about it opening on startup, and more it not closing.

Answer (score 3):

`Option-Click` on the icon in Finder to bring up the `Force Quit` option, and click that.

Otherwise, you can easily do this from the command line via `Terminal` with the following command:

```
ps aux | grep -i spotify | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

or

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -i spotify | awk '{print $2}')
```

I'm not on my Mac right now, so it may actually be `awk '{print $1}'`, but I believe for the OS X output, the second column will give you the PID you are looking for.

**A little more than you asked for:**

If you try to `kill` or `kill -9` a non-existent PID, `kill` will vomit some confusing "help" output to STDERR.  If you want to avoid this output when this command fails (which won't hurt anything), just redirect STDERR to /dev/null, which would make the above commands as follows:

```
ps aux | grep -i [s]potify | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 2>/dev/null
```

or

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -i [s]potify | awk '{print $2}') 2>/dev/null
```

I actually have an extremely handy function in one of my dotfiles, which gets sourced in my `.bash_profile` during every terminal session, which is as follows (please excuse the language -- but this is really what I call it):

```
fuckyou() { ps aux | grep -i "$1" | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 2>/dev/null; }
```

For me, this creates the `fuckyou` command, which takes one argument (the name of whatever offending process I wish to terminate), finds the process ID (PID) of that process and terminates it.

This way, if you were me, you could simply run `fuckyou spotify`.

The one caveat is if there are multiple processes running with the same same, such as Spotify.app and com.spotifyhelper.plist or something, you would either need to explicity specify "Spotify.app", but `grep -i` is case insensitive, so you could say `fuckyou 'Spotify.app'`.

If you wanted to kill all processes under a certain name (as in all processes associated with Spotify), you would need to put the one-liner in a `for` or `while` loop, such as this:

```
for i in $(ps aux | grep -i [s]potify | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 "$i" 2>/dev/null; done
```

This is basically telling Bash to do the follwoing:

- Print all running process names along with their process IDs (`ps aux`)
- Do a case-insensitive search for "spotify" on this output (the bracketed first character will prevent returning the `grep -i spotify` process)
- Grab only the second column of process IDs (which should now only include processes related to Spotify)
- For all of these Spotify-related processes, force each one to terminate